# Pass a ADFS token to a custom STS service

Tags: saml, adfs

I am testing a product that authenticates uses using a custom STS service. The way it used to work is, when a user hits the website using the browser, we issue a redirect to hit the STS service. the STS service authenticates the user by hitting AD and then issues a SAML token with some custom claims for the user. The website then hits the STS once again to get a ActAs token so we can communicate with the data service.

And I had a automation that would mimic this behavior and its working fine in production.

We are not modifying the STS to use ADFS to authenticate instead of hitting the AD directly. So now when I hit the website, the request gets redirected to a ADFS endpoint which authenticates the user and issues a token. Then we hit the custom STS service that would use the token to authenticate the user (instead of hitting AD), add custom claims and issue a SAML token for the user. We then generate a ActAs token using this to finally hit the data service.

I am trying to update my automation for this changed behavior. So what I am doing now is hit the ADFS service, obtain a token and pass the token to the STS service so it can issue me a SAML token.

I am quite an amateur when it comes to windows identity service so i am having hard time trying to get this work. I have successfully obtained the token (Bearer Token) from the ADFS but i cant figureout how to pass this token to my custom STS so it can issue me a SAML token.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

here is the code i am using

```
public static SecurityToken GetSecurityToken()
    {

        var endPoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(@"ADFS endpoint"));
        var msgBinding = new WS2007HttpBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential, false);
        msgBinding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
        msgBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;

        var factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(msgBinding, endPoint);
        factory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;
        factory.Credentials.SupportInteractive = true;
        factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "user";
        factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "pwd";

        var rst = new RequestSecurityToken
        {
            RequestType = RequestTypes.Issue,
            KeyType = KeyTypes.Bearer,
            AppliesTo = new EndpointReference(@"custom STS endpoint")
        };

        return factory.CreateChannel().Issue(rst);
    }
public static void GetUserClaimsFromSecurityTokenService(SecurityToken secToken)
    {
        var securityTokenManager = new SecurityTokenHandlerCollectionManager(string.Empty);
        securityTokenManager[string.Empty] = SecurityTokenHandlerCollection.CreateDefaultSecurityTokenHandlerCollection();

        var trustChannelFactory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(Binding, new EndpointAddress("custom STS endpoint"))
        {
            TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13,
            SecurityTokenHandlerCollectionManager = securityTokenManager,

        };

        var rst = new RequestSecurityToken(RequestTypes.Issue)
        {
            AppliesTo = new EndpointReference("website url"),
            TokenType = SamlSecurityTokenHandler.Assertion
        };

        var channel = (WSTrustChannel)trustChannelFactory.CreateChannel();

        channel.Open(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15));

        try
        {
            RequestSecurityTokenResponse rstr;
            SecurityToken token = channel.Issue(rst, out rstr);

            var genericToken = (GenericXmlSecurityToken)token;
            var req = new SamlSecurityTokenRequirement();
            var handler = new SamlSecurityTokenHandler(req)
            {
                Configuration = new SecurityTokenHandlerConfiguration()
            };

            var newToken = handler.ReadToken(new XmlNodeReader(genericToken.TokenXml));
        }
        finally
        {
            channel.Close();
        }
    }
```